# jQuery change css background when y-axis scroll reaches a certain depth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After scrolling down 600px, I would like a css background-image to appear from no image to a decided background-image (image 1); however, above 600px, I would like to change to another image (image 2). I want this action to repeat itself without having to refresh the page, as well.

Here is my code:

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 800;             
    // set to whatever you want it to be

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
       $("square").css("background-image", "url(images/comp_rel/square.png)");
    }
    else
    {
        $("square").css("background-image","url(images/comp_rel/Box.gif)");
    }
});
```

I know I'm missing something simple, I just can't figure it out. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me:

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {

    var y_scroll_pos = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var scroll_pos_test = 800;             
    // set to whatever you want it to be

   if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
       $("#square").css("background-color", "#00ff00");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#square").css("background-color", "#0000ff");
   }
})
```

only replace css property from background-color to background-image

Comment: It displays the image as soon as I start to scroll, which I don't want. And when you scroll back up to the top of the page, the image does not disappear.